# how to implement traverse use foldMap

Tags: haskell, typeclass

foldMap can be implemented by traverse as :

```
foldMap f = getConst . traverse (Const . f)
```

so, my question is how to implement traverse by foldMap:

```
traverse f = ...
```

OR

```
it Can't be accomplished ?
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Hint: `Foldable => Traversable`.

Comment: What progress have you made so far?

Answer (score 5):

There are `Foldable` instances for which it can't be done.

```
data Blonk a = Blink | Blank

instance Functor Blonk where
    fmap f Blink = Blink
    fmap f Blank = Blank

instance Foldable Blonk where
    foldMap f _ = mempty
```

The above are the only possible total, law-abiding implementations of `Functor` and `Foldable` for `Blonk`. Now there is a law for `Traversable`:

```
traverse Identity = Identity
```

Let's see how it plays out, under the assumption that `traverse` is implemented in terms of `foldMap`, that is, that there are some terms `g` and `h` (which may mention `f` if they like) for which:

```
traverse f = g . foldMap h
```

Then:

```
traverse f x = g (foldMap h x)
             = g mempty
-- THEREFORE
traverse Identity x = g mempty
```

Note that `g mempty` does not depend on `x`, hence must either be `Identity Blink` or `Identity Blank` to fit the type. In the former case,

```
traverse Identity Blank = Identity Blink
                       != Identity Blank
```

and the law is violated. Similarly `traverse Identity Blink` is a witness that the law is violated in the other case.

(And, just to prove I'm not pulling any punches, there is a law abiding `Traversable` instance:

```
instance Traversable Blonk where
    traverse f Blink = pure Blink
    traverse f Blank = pure Blank
```

)

Comment: Thanks to semantic saturation, "blink" just seems like a sound effect to me now instead of a legitimate English word.

Comment: How did you get from `traverse f x = g (foldMap h x)` to `traverse f x = g mempty`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson From the definition of `foldMap`, namely, `foldMap f _ = mempty`.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Wagner gave a very good example of a type with a valid `Traversable` instance that cannot be defined in terms of its `Foldable` instance. But there are also types with valid `Functor` and `Foldable` instances that *don't* have valid `Traversable` instances. The main reason for this is that `Foldable` has practically no laws.

For example, if we wanted, we could write

```
instance Foldable IO where
  foldMap _ _ = mempty
```

Such an instance is more confusing than useful, but there's nothing inherently *wrong* with it. But what happens when we try to write an instance of `Traversable IO`?

```
traverse f m = _1
-- m :: IO a
-- f :: a -> f b
-- _1 :: f (IO b)
```

OK, so we need to make something of type `f (IO b)`. We don't have anything wrapped in `f` yet, so we can't use `<*>` to make it; we can only use `pure`.

```
traverse f m = pure _2
-- m :: IO a
-- f :: a -> f b
-- _2 :: IO b
```

Uh oh. We know how to make `f b` values, but we have no way to make `b` values. Sometimes `IO` lets us punt using exceptions, but the `Traversable` identity law doesn't let us get away with that this time.